# php - Division by 0

Tags: php, undefined, offset

thanks a lot mate!
Now I've got another error: Warning: Division by zero
This is the rest of code:

```
while($i<$n_utenti)
{
    $query3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM valutazione WHERE email='$lista_utenti[$i]'"); 
    $indice=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) //acquisisco le votazioni dell'utente considerato per il confronto
    {
        $album_utente_confronto[$indice]=$row['id_album'];
        $voti_utente_confronto[$indice]=$row['voto'];
        $indice++;
    }
    //trovo gli album che sono stati valutati da entrambi gli utenti
    $indice=0;
    $n_album_loggato=count($album_utente_loggato);
    $n_album_confronto=count($album_utente_confronto);
    $ind=0;
    for($indice=0;$indice<$n_album_loggato; $indice++)
    {
        $index=0;
        while($index<$n_album_confronto)
        {
            if($album_utente_loggato[$indice]==$album_utente_confronto[$index])
            {
                $album_comuni[$ind]=$album_utente_loggato[$indice];
                $ind++;
            }
            $index++;
        }
    }
    //mi trovo i voti relativi agli album comuni per l'utente loggato
    $n_album_comuni = count($album_comuni);
    $indice=0;
    $i_comuni=0;
    for($indice=0;$indice<$n_album_comuni; $indice++)
    {
        $index=0;
        $trovato=false;
        while($index<$n_album_loggato && $trovato==false)
        {
            if($album_comuni[$indice]==$album_utente_loggato[$index])
            {
                $voti_comuni_logged[$i_comuni] = $voti_utente_loggato[$index];
                $trovato = true;
                $i_comuni++;
            }
            else
            {
                $index++;
            }               
        }           
    }
    //mi trovo i voti relativi agli album comuni per l'utente confrontato
    $indice=0;
    $i_comuni=0;
    for($indice=0;$indice<$n_album_comuni; $indice++)
    {
        $index=0;
        $trovato=false;
        while($index<$n_album_confronto && $trovato==false)
        {
            if($album_comuni[$indice]==$album_utente_confronto[$index])
            {
                $voti_comuni_confronto[$i_comuni] = $voti_utente_confronto[$index];
                $trovato = true;
                $i_comuni++;
            }
            else
            {
                $index++;
            }               
        }           
    }


    $correlation[$i] = Correlation($voti_comuni_logged, $voti_comuni_confronto);


    $i++;//chiusura while
}

//Displaying the calculated Correlation:
print $correlation[0];




}


//The functions that work behind the scene to calculate the
//correlation

function Correlation($arr1, $arr2)
{        
$correlation = 0;

$k = SumProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2);
$ssmd1 = SumSquareMeanDeviation($arr1);
$ssmd2 = SumSquareMeanDeviation($arr2);

$product = $ssmd1 * $ssmd2;

$res = sqrt($product);

$correlation = $k / $res;

return $correlation;
}

function SumProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2)
{
$sum = 0;

$num = count($arr1);

for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
    $sum = $sum + ProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2, $i);
}

return $sum;
}

function ProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2, $item)
{
return (MeanDeviation($arr1, $item) * MeanDeviation($arr2, $item));
}

function SumSquareMeanDeviation($arr) 
{
$sum = 0;

$num = count($arr);

for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
    $sum = $sum + SquareMeanDeviation($arr, $i);
}

return $sum;
}

function SquareMeanDeviation($arr, $item)
{
return MeanDeviation($arr, $item) * MeanDeviation($arr, $item);
} 

function SumMeanDeviation($arr)
{
$sum = 0;

$num = count($arr);

for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
    $sum = $sum + MeanDeviation($arr, $i);
}

return $sum;
}

function MeanDeviation($arr, $item)
{
$average = Average($arr);

return $arr[$item] - $average;
}    

function Average($arr)
{
$sum = Sum($arr);
$num = count($arr);

return $sum/$num;
}

function Sum($arr)
{
return array_sum($arr);
}
```

the error is in the function correlation, in this row:
$correlation = $k / $res;
Why it give me the error?
I shoul have a value between 0 and 1

Comment: Beware of SQL injection if $_SESSION['Mail'] comes from user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this:

```
while($i<=$n_utenti)
```

To this:

```
while($i<$n_utenti)
```

`$n_utenti` is larger by one than the count of records in `$lista_utenti`.

Otherwise it would be cleaner to use

```
foreach($lista_uteni as $email){
```

based loop. (And you could phase out one temp variable this way.)

Comment: thanks a lot! I've edited the first post with a new error, can you look there please?

Comment: Generally it is not a good practice the change the question post's focus in this site... Otherwise somehow your $res seems to zero. You should debug your variables. Maybe a few print could help.

Comment: thanks, I've changed values in the database and now standard deviation isn't 0